# Running another program in console

Tags: c#, console, exe

Is it possible to run another console application in running console. Lets say I got program that write hello world, i got her as exe file. Now I am running another program, can i run the other one in the second one? i want to run the hello world in the second program, its like running a process but in this console.
I want to run the code and then continue the program that called it.

Is it possible some how?

I didn't find the answer anywhere... My idea is to write scripts and shell for them which will run them. If you got another idea i would like to hear it to.
I want it in C# so cygwin or any other shell (which is not c#) won't help me.

Comment: @I4V as far as I understand OP is asking to run another process but in same console

Answer (score 1):

You should use System.Diagnostics.Proces class to run the secondary process [More details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

Comment: Correct me if im wrong but this open the other process in another console. Can i open it in the console that is already open?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by same console? you want to run a program and get the result, 
If you don't want it to run in the background, the use:

```
Process p = Process.Start("exe fullname");
p.WaitForExit();
if (p.ExitCode == 0)
{
    //everything is good
}
else
{
    //the program wasn't successful
}
```

If however, you want it in the background, then you need to use a 
[Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx).

[Here is a complete article regading tasks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/189374/The-Basics-of-Task-Parallelism-via-C)

Note: If it's another Console application, and you want to use the result, then use [ProcessStartInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx)